# Flutter show same page on webpage

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

can flutter redirect to webpage that show same page as on flutter?

The idea was to make a profile that can be seeing from the website. So the apps can generate some link that can be show the profile in a webpage.